# Update single field in a document (document.update($set)?)

Tags: mongodb, update, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2

Can't seem to figure out how to update a single field.

Whatever I try, to update one field (picture: "url") the rest of the fields are being removed and set to null.

I use the following command now:

```
Meteor.users.update(
          userId,
          {
            $set: {
              profile: {
                picture: fileURL
              }
            }
          }
        );
```

And this is what happens with the rest of the object after update.

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "_id": "J222CqhR777GcXD",
      "createdAt": "Tue Sep 11 2018 19:23:55 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
      "email": "scott@example.com",
      "profile": {
        "about": null,
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "phone": null,
        "picture": "https://image.path/source.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there another operator I am missing or some other way to do this?

In another document I am querying for all the data before, storing it in a React state and then passing all the fields that I have not changed to the update, but that seems rather inefficient and unnecessary step(???)

Is there really not a way to update just a single field without affecting the rest of the document?

cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to rewrite like so (profile.picture in one line with dot notation), this works:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    userId,
    {
        $set: {
            'profile.picture': fileURL
        }
    }
);
```

Answered by @coagmano on [meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-update-one-field-of-meteor-user/45596/2)

Comment: To specify a in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation. As you have used here like   'profile.picture': fileURL.

Answer (score 1):

As per mongodb documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) The [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

```
{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

**Dot Notation**

MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.

***For Arrays***

To specify or access an element of an array by the zero-based index position, concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index position, and enclose in quotes:

```
"<array>.<index>"
```

For example, given the following field in a document:

```
{
   ...
   contribs: [ "Turing machine", "Turing test", "Turingery" ],
   ...
}
```

***For Embedded Documents***

To specify or access a field of an embedded document with dot notation, concatenate the embedded document name with the dot (.) and the field name, and enclose in quotes:

```
"<embedded document>.<field>"
```

For example, given the following field in a document:

```
{
   ...
   name: { first: "Alan", last: "Turing" },
   contact: { phone: { type: "cell", number: "111-222-3333" } },
   ...
}
```

- To specify the field named last in the name field, use the dot
  notation **`"name.last"`**.
- To specify the number in the phone document in the contact field, use
  the dot notation **`"contact.phone.number"`**.

> **Note:** The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

For further your reference [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)